# Using personal Office 365 Outlook with company 365 email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I have a personal Office 365 subscription and Outlook application on Win10. I would like to use it to access my company email which is another 365 account. The company account is authorised for web applications but not desktop application download (more $$ I suppose).

When I try to add the company email account in outlook, it says "something went wrong" (helpful).

Should this be possible? Or Microsoft doesn't allow me to use "My" Outlook with the company email because "they" haven't paid extra for offline application license?

Comment: As long as the domainnames are not the same, and I'm sure its not the case for you, it should be possible. So you have outlook with either a subscription or one-time fee license to install outlook, then you can have any outlook account on it. But make sure you have logged into webmail at least once. Otherwise it may give you a "something went wrong" trying to configure it.

Comment: The company account may need to be [manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/server-settings-you-ll-need-from-your-email-provider-c82de912-adcc-4787-8283-45a1161f3cc3) configured as an Exchange account in Outlook if Outlook fails to auto-configure it.

Comment: @JW0914 is right. If no one in the company can use outlook, its possible they did not set the autodiscover DNS records on the domain which is why its not automatically configuring itself. In that case a manual setup with Exchange or Office365 is necesesary, depending on what client you use.

Comment: Thank you @LPChip. I found the IMAP and SMTP settings information in the company 365 email settings, tried adding the account manually to my outlook - It keeps popping up a dialog asking me for my password, which I enter correctly. When I click OK it just pops back up.